# Login authentication successful but remote server not opening in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

After successful login, remote Windows Server 2003 is not showing any desktop. It's just idle. I am unable to see any button or anything. To get this remote connection I am using the MSTSC command.

Comment: Do you have any other type of access to the server, like web, or ftp? your issue sounds like an out-of-memory problem, causing resources to not load.

Comment: There is no FTP access for that server but a bunch of IIS service and windows services are running in it.This login problem differs PC(personal computer) to PC.in some of the PC i can able to login and use the server successfully but only in some system i cant able to use.

Comment: Try to use a non-Windows RDP, like rdesktop on Ubuntu. It might show you a more detailed error log.